# Is transit time of 40 mins enough for a transit at Dusseldorf airport?

Tags: visas, transit, airport-security, short-connections, dus

I am flying from U.S. to India via Germany(2 stops - Dusseldorf and Munich). There is a 40 min layover at Dusseldorf and 1 h 40 min layover at Munich.
I am concerned if I will be able to make to the connection to Munich. Is 40 mins enough time for a transit? Also, I am not a US citizen and will require an airport transit visa, which I am planning to get before I travel. Are there extra clearances/security checks required for Dusseldorf-Munich transit for people on transit visas, which may cause delays?

Comment: you need a schengen visa and not a transit visa.

Comment: @Dirty-flow AFAIK there is now a standard Uniform 'c' visa for both purposes. Also, for the OP, I'd like to add that being an Indian citizen with a valid or just expired US visa, you would not have required a Schengen visa if you would have been transiting only at one Schengen Airport, but since your trip involves intra-Schengen travel, you will need to clear immigration at the first airport you land in, in Germany.

Comment: 40 minutes seems awful quick to pass through immigration and catch another plane.  Also, you may need to reenter through security to change from the international to the domestic terminal (one time at Dusseldorf I had to do so, another time I didn't).

Comment: It's 40 minutes if your first flight arrives on time. If it is delayed by just 20 minutes then it goes from "very, very short" to "absolutely impossible".

Comment: It's very tight. Please add airline + dept airport +  arr airport and whether it's a single ticket. If this is a single Lufthansa ticket and nothing is delayed, you will make it, but there is no room for contingency. There are plenty of DUS to MUC flights but it depends if you are coming in from MIA or New York. Both the Mumbai and Delhi flights leave around noon time from MUC

Answer (score 3):

40 minutes could be enough but it could become scarce. As your second leg is a domestic Schengen flight, you will need to get through security and passport check. With only 40 minutes between the flights it's likely to miss the flight to Munich.

Answer (score 2):

If all your flights are booked on the same ticket, this means that the minimum connection time for this connection is met (unless your travel agent circumvented some rules, which they normally not do).

Passport checks in Dusseldorf are usually quite quick. Please keep the comments to your original post in mind - you will need a "proper" Schengen visa for the trip since you have an intra-Schengen leg. In any case, I would suggest the following:

1. Before your first flight, ask at the counter if you can get a seat near the front of the plane - this will increase the likelihood of being one of the first people to leave the plane, thus avoiding the queue at passport check.
2. If point 1 does not work, ask a flight attendent for help before landing in Dusseldorf - he/she may help you by asking everyone to step aside after having reached parking position, so you can be one of the first to deboard.