# Do I have to collect my luggage on connecting flights into Germany?

Tags: luggage, germany, lufthansa

I am looking at flying from Newark International to Munich on Lufthansa, and then to Berlin-Tegel. I believe it is all booked as one trip; however, flights entering the United States require you to retrieve baggage and then re-check it after going through Customs. Is it the same for Germany?

I am somewhat worried because there is only 50 minutes between flights, and the waits for Customs and the baggage claim may be long.

Comment: As Relaxed has explained it's likely (but not certain) your baggage will be sent through.  I have found it is almost impossible to "truly determine," whether or not, your baggage will go sent through: it depends on the airlines, if you change airlines, what is happening on the day etc. And as others have mentioned on the linked question, Munchen is a quick airport to get through. But for me 50 minutes is way too quick. It's poor that they booked that connection. Note too that it's totally possible your baggage will miss the connection, even if you make it. Can they change you to the next?

Comment: If München to Berlin is on Lufthansa, it is extremely likely that your baggage is checked through. München has a minimum connection time of 45 minutes (LH to LH), so, your connection time is sufficient. Also, you come in from the west, where more than often, you will get in early. If you happen to come in late, there will be agents to help you.

Comment: I once made a US->Schengen connection in Munich in 30 minutes between touch-down and *departure* of the other flight, which was precisely departing from the opposite end of the other terminal (by running). So it is certainly doable in case your US flight does not come in late. Please also have a look at the answers for this post: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33762/is-transit-time-of-40-mins-enough-for-a-transit-at-dusseldorf-airport/39872#39872 for "inspirations" on how to get the connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not the same. Whether that's the case for a given journey will depend on a few details but, unlike the US, there is no blanket requirement to pick up your luggage and walk it through customs when entering Germany or the EU. Usually, in Europe, your luggage will be routed to your final destination and you will clear customs there.

You haven't provided much detail but I expect it won't be necessary to collect your luggage in this case. However, immigration formalities (passport check by the police, Schengen entry stamp, etc.) will have to be completed in Munich.

There is some info on transit time in Munich in [Is 1½ hours enough for a transit at Munich Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/is-1%C2%BD-hours-enough-for-a-transit-at-munich-airport)

Comment: Specifically, I am a student finishing a degree at a German university. I booked through Vayama which is supposedly somewhat sketchy, so I had concerns as to what to do about the baggage.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to collect your baggage before catching your connecting flight. When you check in your luggage at the check-in desk at the airport, let them know that you would like your baggage check-in straight through to your final destination.